# How does a variable as a second statement in a for-loop work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

I tried to find an answer to this question, please forgive me if I am just too stupid to find it.
I am sorry if that's the case. But I have this loop and I have no idea why it does what it does.
This is an exercise from the book "Eloquent JavaScript" by Marjin Haverbeke (Page 89, if anyone's interested)

My question is how the variable "node" works as a second statement.

Any explanation much appreciated!

Thanks,
Ben

```
list = { value: 'one', rest: { value: 'two', rest: { value: 'three', rest: null }}};

function listToArray(list) {
    let array = [];
    for (let node = list; node ; node = node.rest) {
      array.push(node.value);
    }
    return array;
  }

console.log(listToArray(list));
```

Output: [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

Comment: It's using the JavaScript concept of Truthiness. For more info, see [Truthy page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second statement of the `for` loop, you need to provide a condition on which the loop should run or stop. So, it should be something that gives an output of either `true` or `false`.

In this case, `node` will have some value. That value is evaluated as `true` if it is anything other than `0` or `null`. So, when the `node.rest` returns `null`. The condition will become `false`. Hence, stopping the loop.

Comment: `0` and `null` are not the only "falsy" values ... there's an empty string, `undefined`, `NaN`, `-0` and `0n`

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. As stated above my problem is (now that you guys pointed it out) more about wrapping my head around the structure of the nested list. My quest is now to understand when exactly `node.rest` returns `null`, but that's something my brain needs some rewiring for :)

Comment: @SMEETT ... you assign `node = node.rest` after every iteration, you can see in the object that node becomes null when node was `{ value: 'three', rest: null }` ... since the `rest` property of that node is `null`

Comment: @Jaromanda ... I feel so stupid now, lol. But yeah, that makes an awful lot of sense. Very interesting to see a for-loop used like that, this is eye-opening. Thanks a ton, this made my day!

Comment: @SMEETT - it's a *very* common pattern for a for-loop

Comment: @Jaromanda – I can imagine. All I used so far was the absolute classic (i = 0; i < x; i++), so this is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking how `node` works as the second expression inside the `for` loop. Javascript just evaluates that value as true of false, it's like saying `!!node`.

```
// to simplify the for loop, the variable node starts with the list
// and if the node exists executes the code block inside and continues the loop
// when node.rest becomes null the loop exits 
for (let node = list; node ; node = node.rest) {
      array.push(node.value);
}
```

To further explain how for loop works, it consists of three expressions, the initializer, condition (which js will evaluate to true or false), and the final expression.

```
for (
  let i = 0; // initializes the variable i
  i < 10;    // condition that determines whether the loop should continue next iteration or not
  i++;       // final-expression which increments the i variable to be used in the next iteration

) {
 // code block
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir!
Thank you very much for your answer. I think I am able to narrow down what I don't understand. I struggle to wrap my head around the nested list. That a binding can act as a statement itself is something I actually knew, I was just confused by something else. This nasty little program here is giving me a hard time :) Thanks again!